# VBA - "Application-defined or object-defined error" when setting class properties

Tags: excel, vba, class

I'm writing a small Excel macro, and I have a class called EventClass.

I loop over every row in a worksheet and add each row as an EventClass object in a Collection of EventClass objects - with each cell in the row being a property of the class.

Here is the code:

```
Dim iRow As Integer
For iRow = 2 To oSourceWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Set evEvent = New EventClass
    evEvent.OwnerConsolidated = oSourceWorksheet.Rows(iRow, 1)
    evEvent.OwnerUser = oSourceWorksheet.Rows(iRow, 2)
    evEvent.ProductsAF = oSourceWorksheet.Rows(iRow, 3)
    evEvent.ProductsGL = oSourceWorksheet.Rows(iRow, 4)
    evEvent.ProductsMZ = oSourceWorksheet.Rows(iRow, 5)
    evEvent.Quarter = oSourceWorksheet.Rows(iRow, 6)
    evEvent.Attendees = oSourceWorksheet.Rows(iRow, 7)
    evEvent.CampaignName = oSourceWorksheet.Rows(iRow, 8)

    colEvents.Add evEvent

Next iRow
```

The error is being thrown on the first property set, and I have no idea why.

Let me know if you need to see any other code or anything!

Thanks guys!

Comment: Could you post up the function prototype for .OwnerConsolidated?

Comment: Sorry - as in the "Get" and "Let" functions within the EventClass class?

Comment: Yup. I think you have misplaced property let / set.

Comment: @Bathsheba should that not raise an "Object does not support this property or method" error?

Comment: @BethSheba - it was actually both you're suggestion and the answer below that fixed my problem - thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get this error when attempting to use the `.Rows` property of a range object, with two arguments, even though intellisense tells me that you can provide two arguments:

[image]

Try doing this:

```
With oSourceWorksheet.UsedRange
    evEvent.OwnerConsolidated = .Cells(iRow, 1)
    evEvent.OwnerUser = .Cells(iRow, 2)
    evEvent.ProductsAF = .Cells(iRow, 3)
    evEvent.ProductsGL = .Cells(iRow, 4)
    evEvent.ProductsMZ = .Cells(iRow, 5)
    evEvent.Quarter = .Cells(iRow, 6)
    evEvent.Attendees = .Cells(iRow, 7)
    evEvent.CampaignName = .Cells(iRow, 8)
End With
```